# Microsoft edge won't work after installing CorelDRAW X4

Tags: microsoft-edge, coreldraw

I had even changed registry permission for All Application Packages but Microsoft edge still not opening. Help please

Comment: Please provide more (lots more) information. Why did you change permissions on this registry key? What errors are you seeing in event viewer? Is CorelDraw compatible with Windows 10?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.